# соцсеть одноклассники: Как упомянуть друга в репосте из iframe приложения?

Tags: iframe, одноклассники

Есть *iframe* приложение, использую метод `postMediatopic` *Javascript API* для размещения поста на стене пользователя. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в тексте этого поста упомянуть человека. Нужно, чтобы в итоге в тексте были ссылки на профиль упомянутого человека. Может есть какие-нибудь специальные последовательности символов, вроде `@profile1233243`